# Consolidate excel files from folders that are found in list of foldernames

Tags: python

I have a list of foldernames and I want to go through the folders according to this list and consolidate the excel files found in those folders.

Example: 
Say I have the following directory:"C:/Users/XXX/Documents/File Tracking"
This includes the folders A, B, C, D, E, F
Now I have a list of folder names: lst=[A,B,D]

Now I want to go through the folders A, B, D and consolidate the excel files found in these folders into one, ignoring the folders not mentioned in this list.

This is some code that works if I want to consolidate the files from all subfolders

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("C:/Users/XXX/Documents/File Tracking/*"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work just fine. Check comments in code for more explanation.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# assumes you have a list of the file paths
def consolidate_excel_files(folder_paths: list) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # used to collect all dfs from folders
    df_collection = []

    for folder in folder_paths:
        # makes sure your path is right
        if os.path.isdir(folder):
            # list comprehension that gets all excel files into a data frame
            # will ignore any stray file that is not .xlsx or .xls
            all_files_as_df = [pd.read_excel(os.path.absnpath(file)) 
                               for file in os.listdir(folder) 
                               if os.splitext(file)[1] in ['.xlsx' or '.xls']]
            # we only want a 1d list when we use pd.append, so we extend instead
            df_collection.extend(all_files_as_df)

    # assuming the index is not important
    return pd.append(df_collection, ignore_index=True)
```

There is probably a less verbose way of doing this if you assume a few things, but this will work.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it in the most straightforward way - simply get a list of directories in chosen base dir, filter it and look for the spreadsheets inside each of them. See the boilerplate below:

```
import glob
import os

path = "C:/Users/XXX/Documents/File Tracking/"
allowed = ["A", "B", "D"]

# list of first-level directories from allowed list
dirs = [name for name in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, name)) and name in allowed]

for dirname in dirs:
    # iterate over all files that match pattern, for example, xlsx
    for file_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, dirname, "*.xlsx")):
        # process each file
```